# How to alter table in Azure SQL without query editor

Tags: sql, azure, alter

I am using SQL Azure recently.But when I connect SQL Azure database in Sql Server management studio then their is no option for alter the table and stored procedure.

If anybody have solution for this without query so please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,
**First:** Go to your azure account https://portal.azure.com
and follow these steps:

- Click on `sql servers` from Browser All option.
- Then select your server
- and select your database
- Click option `Open in Visual studio`

There you can alter tables and procedures.

**Second:**
Here you can only alter your procedure not tables.

- Open Sql server Management studio(by Run window SSMS).
- Then select your database
- Expend Programmability folder then procedures folder.
- Right click on procedure( which you wants to edit).
- Change text create to alter Buz it is already created in your db.

[image]

Comment: First idea is somehow messy. I only reordered columns and pushed update to server, It lost all the FK relationships.

Comment: @batmaci, that solution for alter table without query. Can you explain your scenario where you lost fk keys

Comment: I have done just like you said, using VS 2015. There is designer when you open in sql servers but somehow designer is read only, is it not possible to change things. I tried to alter query below the designer and clicked "update" button. It just got messy. 2nd option is much better i believe. I just tried to execute an "Alter table ... " tsql query and all works fine.